# annotate attribute as foreign key in JPA entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

**Q:** I have one class called `Person` and I want to create an hierarchy between `Person`'s using a parentId attribute of type UUID instead of using an attribute of type Person.

DDL for person table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.person (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    parent_id uuid NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_parent_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES public.person (id)
);
```

Current implentation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Wanted implementation

```
public class Person {

    //implementation from above

    @AnnotationThatSpecifiesThatThisIsAForeignKeyToAGivenEntity
    private UUID parentId;
}
```

I dont know how to specify that a filed (parentId from above) is a foreign key

Comment: If you already have the table definition, have you tried just marking it as a Column(name="parent_id")?

Comment: Yes, it works this way. But I think that maybe is not the right approach not to specify inside the entity that this is not a foreign key

Comment: Why not? Your entity and application doesn't care - as long as you set it to a value that exists in the reference table anyway. A reference mapping (ManyToOne) has JPA set the FK value for you, but if you don't want that and want a basic mapping -  a basic mapping in JPA is all that is available. You didn't mention why you want this though - are you looking for some special functionality or reason to use a basic over a reference?

Comment: I guess you need your Person class inserted after the Parent. JPA does not have annotations for that - I don't think Hibernate does either. In EclipseLink,  since there is no object level reference for it to determine a specific Parent must come before a specific Person, you would have to tell it to process ALL parents before Person instances via native customizers and its https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.8/org/eclipse/persistence/descriptors/ClassDescriptor.html#addConstraintDependency(java.lang.Class). IDK if hibernate has something equivalent.